# Why is my custom cursor's position way off?

Tags: html, css, cursor

So I used an online cursor converter to convert my .png icon to a .cur icon. And when I tried it out, the icon was off about 10 pixels to the right and the top. After some googling, I found out that the cursor's **hotspot** was set "incorrectly". I tried to edit it from the VS 2012 Image Editor. It wouldn't let me.

I've fixed the problem, already and when SO lets me, I'll put up the answer.

NOTE: I'm using IE 11 on Windows 7. And it does not like this piece of CSS:

```
cursor: url(../Images/deletecursor.cur) 5 -5, pointer;
```

IE completely ignored it. I had to set it as:

```
cursor: url(../Images/deletecursor.cur), pointer;
```

Which is part 1 of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in IE I had to have the CSS as such:

```
cursor: url(../Images/cursor.cur), pointer;
```

Then the way I fixed it was to go to this website: http://www.cursor.cc/? and use it to set the hotspot (graphically). Afterwards, it all worked as I expected to.

Now granted, I won't be accepting my answer as the answer. Because I'm sure someone else will run into a similar problem. And there will be Opera, Firefox, and Chrome versions of this issue. Also, I'm sure that there will be javascript, jquery, and plain css solutions for other browsers as well.

With that said, the plain CSS (for any browser other than IE) to fix the hotspot issue (whether the icon is .png, .gif, .cur, .ani, etc.) is:

```
cursor: url(../Images/deletecursor.cur) 5 -5, pointer;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was finding a solution to this IE problem in the last few days.